# Show different SELECT menu when different radio button selected

Tags: jquery, radio-button, select-menu

I have five radio buttons as follow:

```
<input type="radio" id="Gold" name="PackageID" value="77"/>
<input type="radio" id="Silver" name="PackageID" value="73"/>
<input type="radio" id="Bronze" name="PackageID" value="72"/>
<input type="radio" id="Copper" name="PackageID" value="94"/>
<input type="radio" id="Tester" name="PackageID" value="71"/>
```

and following two select menues:

```
<select name="DripFeed" id="select3-basic" tabindex="1" data-placeholder="Days.." class="span1">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
</select>

<select name="DripFeed1" id="select3-basic" tabindex="1" data-placeholder="Days.." class="span2">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="2">3</option>
<option value="2">4</option>
<option value="2">5</option>
<option value="2">6</option>
</select>
```

Now what I need is that once user select radio buttons with IDs: `Gold, Silver, Bronze, Copper` to show select menu with name `DripFeed` and once user select radio button with ID tester to show select menu with name `DripFeed1`.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can't uncheck a radio and only one radio in the group can be checked, any change would normally be to check it, and if the ID of the checked radio matches `Tester`, show `DripFeed1` and hide `DripFeesd`, otherwise do the opposite :

```
$('[name="PackageID"]').on('change', function() {
    var state = this.id == 'Tester';

    $('[name="DripFeed1"]').toggle(state);
    $('[name="DripFeed"]').toggle(!state);
});
```

Note that ID's are unique, and you're using `select3-basic` multiple times (and the same tabindex).

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/5YE7j/1/)

Comment: awesome works just as I needed. One more thing, if none of above radio buttons is selected, is it possible to show DripFeed1 ?

Comment: Sure is, as you can't uncheck a radio, you could just set it to visible at pageload. If you have more radios than whats in the question, and what you're really trying to do is the opposite of the above code, filterting on the firts four ID's, you'd reverse the condition, something like this -> http://jsfiddle.net/5YE7j/2/ --------